# Every startup i need to manually run fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root

Tags: ubuntu, fsck, ubuntu-18.04

Hi every day when I start my ubuntu 18.04, then it's not starting and gives a below error.

```
(initramfs) exit
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; Run fsck MANUALLY.
    (i.e., without -a or -p options)

fsck exited with status code 4.
The root file system on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root requires manual fsck
```

When I run command `fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`

it solves error but again the next day when I start up my system it shows same error again and needs to run the command again.

Comment: How did you shut down the system? And why?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton That is Ubuntu desktop. Normally after completing day when I leave the office, the time I shutdown my system using go to setting and shut down.

Comment: Did your company ask you to shut down the computer at the end of the day? Normally they are left on, even when not actively in use, so that maintenance can be done after business hours.

Comment: I’m facing with the same issue. Normal shutdown and corrupted FS. Did you find a way to solve it?

Comment: @FlorentMorselli Still I have not got any solutions.

Comment: Try pressing `Alt+SysRq+O` before you shut down the system. This will remount the filesystems as read-only. If that changes the behavior, it will help to identify the cause of the problem.

Comment: A power outage brought me here...

Comment: I have not found solutions. so finally format the system and install the new OS.

Answer (score 0):

Run fsck from the bustbox shell or a USB stick with the "-y" option to repair. Your root filesystem must NOT be mounted. Should be:

Code:
*fsck -y /dev/mapper/mint--vg--root*

solve my problem, solution supported by https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/problems-with-root-file-system-4175663569/